# Blazor WASM, render dynamic html with default browser html elements styles (do not use global styles from MudBlazor)

Tags: html, css, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I'm dynamically rendering custom HTML articles from a database in a Blazor WASM application using MarkupString.

I'm experiencing an issue where default HTML elements are rendered with overridden styles. I believe this is due to MudBlazor applying a CSS reset globally.

Is there a way to render HTML elements with their default styles? I want the HTML article to appear as it does in the HTML editor. For instance, I'd like the  element to display as a bulleted list.

Thanks.

Comment: Default html element styles. For example, <h1>..h6 elements have by default margin. <ul> elements have margin, padding, and list-style-type=disc. w3 school have documented default html elements styles: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp

Comment: And how can i render dynamic html with default styles? I do not want specify all default styles in my app.